# Rails '.js.erb' not rendering partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So, i'm working with rails 3.2.13 and what i'm trying to do is render a partial and then append it to a div using jquery:

`$("#notifications").append("<%=raw escape_javascript(render('layouts/notification')) %>");`

what it does right now, is it appends it to the right div but it doesn't render the partial or anything, it just renders the rails code as a string.. I don't know what i'm doing wrong but i bet its something silly that i'm missing.

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `render_to_string` instead of just `render`

Answer (score 1):

if its a **regular partial**(under the same view) then:-

```
$("#notifications").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'notification')) %>");
```

else

```
$("#notifications").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'layouts/notification')) %>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $("#notifications").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'layouts/notification')) %>");
```

Comment: no that didn't work either and something weird was happening too with that code cause i tried console.log after it and it didn't execute, buy when i took it out it did

Comment: @RAJ... why are you using raw or html_safe when you are rendering a partial?