# Rails 4: escape_javascript render partial not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-modal

In my Rails 4 app, I am trying to display some views as `modals` (with Bootstrap modal), instead of the regular `.html.erb` views.

For instance, I have a `calendar` model, with a custom `analysis` action in the controller:

```
def analysis
  @calendar = Calendar.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Following what is explained in [this tutorial](http://www.benkirane.ch/ajax-bootstrap-modals-rails/) and [that other tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/ej0mhg/open-a-rails-form-with-twitter-bootstrap-modals), I am trying to create the following files:

```
# _dialog.html.erb

<div class="modal fade" id="dialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" 
                data-dismiss="modal" 
                aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>

    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

---

```
# _analysis.html.erb

<p><%= @calendar.name %> Analysis</p>
```

---

```
# analysis.js.erb

// Add the dialog title
$('#dialog h3').html("Calendar Analysis");

// Render calendar analysis
$('.modal-body').html('<%= j render(:partial => 'calendars/analysis') %>');

// Show the dynamic dialog
$('#dialog').modal("show");

// Set focus to the first element
$('#dialog').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('.first_input').focus()
  })
```

Last but not least, I call the modal from a `_heading.html.erb` partial, rendered inside the calendar `show.html.erb` view, with the `<%= render 'analysis' %>` helper and the following link:

```
<%= link_to '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></i>'.html_safe, calendar_analysis_path, :remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window' %>
```

When I launch my app, I then get the following error:

```
undefined method `render' for #<#<Class:0x007fee248d8118>:0x007fee23577ce0>
```

—————

**UPDATE**: I have tried different ways to render the partial:

- [As recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127934/rendering-partial-in-js-erb-file), I tried both `escape_javascript render` and `j render`.
- [As recommended there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313911/rails-js-erb-not-rendering-partial), I have also tried `render_to_string` instead of just `render`.
- As recommended in that other question, I even tried different ways to call the partial, both with `render(:partial => 'calendars/analysis')` and `(render 'calendars/analysis')`.

But none of these solutions worked.

—————

I have done quite a lot of research on that topic and I have to say that I am confused now.

While both tutorials mentioned above recommend this approach, other sources, [including this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370399/rails-js-erb-file-cannot-find-method-render), point out that you cannot render a partial from assets in Rails.

Therefore:

1. What is wrong with my current code?
2. Does the approach I am trying to use make sense at all, and if not, what shoud I do instead?

Comment: does your `analysis.js.erb` live somewhere under the `views` directory?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. `analysis.js.erb` is currently under `app/assets/javascript`. Could that cause the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code under `app/assets` can not call `render`. Actually it can not call almost anything except a very few methods.

Move it somewhere to `app/views/somethings/analysis.js.erb`

Where `somethings` is the name of your controller in plural form, so just put it near the `_analysis.html.erb`.

Comment: You were perfectly correct, this worked like a charm. Thank you very much, I was really struggling with this.