# rails4 js response XSS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, xss

I have a rails4 app. If I submit `<script>alert('haha')</script>` in the form then alert gets displayed, so it doesn't escape js (despite of having `<%= j render @post %>`), so my app is not protected from XSS.

Why is this happening? What should I do?

controller

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
  @post_comment = PostComment.new
  if @post.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: "Post saved!" }
      format.js
    end
  else
    .......
```

_form

```
<%= form_for @post, remote: true, method: :post, class: "post-create-form" do |f| %>
<div class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none">
  <ul class="errors" style="display:none">
    <%= render 'layouts/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Share something useful..", class: "form-control post-create-body" %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.button "Share", class: "btn btn-primary btn-create-post", data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Saving..."} %>
</div>
```

create.js.erb

```
$("ul.errors").html("");
<% if @post.errors.any? %>
    $('.alert-danger').show();
    $('ul.errors').show();
    <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        $("ul.errors").append($("<li />").html("<%= message.html_safe %>"));
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    $('ul.errors').hide();
    $('.alert-danger').hide();
    $('.post-index').prepend('<%= j render @post %>');
    $('.post-create-body').val('');
    $('.btn-create-post').prop('disabled',true);
<% end %>
```

Comment: As per [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557374/rails-4-escape-javascript-render-partial-not-working?rq=1), where is create.js.erb in your project directory?

Comment: Yeah it's in `view/posts/create.js.erb`. If I type in simple text then everything works fine.